# Comparar chave de dicionário com um inteiro

Tags: python, dicionário

Meu professor deu um problema a ser resolvido pela turma.

> Dada uma frase, queremos saber qual a letra que mais aparece, trabalhando sempre com letra minúsculas, ou seja, desconsiderando a distinção dentre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Eu codifiquei a seguinte solução, em python:

```
def letra_q_mais_aparece(frase):
alfabeto = {"a":0, "b":0, "c":0, "d":0, 'e':0, 'f':0, 'g':0, 'h':0, 'i':0, 'j':0, 'k':0, 'l':0, 'm':0, 'n':0, 'o':0,'p':0,'q':0,'r':0,'s':0,'t':0,'u':0,'v':0,'w':0,'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}
new_frase = frase.lower()
count = 0
mais_repete = ''
for letra in new_frase:
    if letra in alfabeto:
        alfabeto[letra] += 1

for letra in alfabeto:
    if alfabeto.keys() > count:
        count += letra.keys()
        mais_repete += letra
return mais_repete
a = input()
print(letra_q_mais_aparece(a))
```

O problema acontece no segundo for. Eu queria comparar cada chave do dicionário com a variável contadora, para então localizar a letra que mais se repete, mas dá um erro que diz que:

> if alfabeto.keys() > count:
>   TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict_keys' and 'int'

Como posso fazer esse código funcionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução. Usei o comando 'get' para obter os valores associados às letras.

```
def letra_q_mais_aparece(frase):
alfabeto = {"a":0, "b":0, "c":0, "d":0, 'e':0, 'f':0, 'g':0, 'h':0, 'i':0, 'j':0, 'k':0, 'l':0, 'm':0, 'n':0, 'o':0,'p':0,'q':0,'r':0,'s':0,'t':0,'u':0,'v':0,'w':0,'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}
new_frase = frase.lower()
count = 0
mais_repete = ''
for letra in new_frase:
    if letra in alfabeto:
        alfabeto[letra] += 1

for letra in alfabeto:
    if alfabeto.get(letra) > count:
        count = alfabeto.get(letra)
        mais_repete = letra
return mais_repete
a = input()
print(letra_q_mais_aparece(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que o exercício seja pra fins didáticos, mas vale a pena apontar que o `Counter`, da biblioteca padrão `collections`, é uma boa ferramenta pra esse caso:

```
from collections import Counter

frase = 'A rápida raposa marrom pula sobre o cão preguiçoso.'

contador = Counter(frase.lower())
print(contador)  # Counter({' ': 8, 'o': 7, 'a': 6, 'r': 6, 'p': 4, 's': 3, 'i': 2, 'm': 2 ...

# Remover caracteres que não são do alfabeto.
# Iteramos sobre uma cópia do Counter pra não ter problemas com a remoção de elementos durante iteração
for chave in contador.copy():
    # O `isalpha()` tem a vantagem de manter caracteres acentuados (ç, ã, etc)
    if not chave.isalpha():
        contador.pop(chave)

print(contador)  # Counter({'o': 7, 'a': 6, 'r': 6, 'p': 4, 's': 3, 'i' ...
# Elemento mais comum e sua contagem
print(contador.most_common(1))  # [('o', 7)]
```

Comment: Sim, é para fim didático, mas obrigada pela dica!